Unable to create file using Spark on Client Mode in airflow-spark-docker
Getting this error in airflow:

org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaIOException: [DELTA_CANNOT_CREATE_LOG_PATH] Cannot create file:/opt/bitnami/spark/my_lakehouse/staging/customers/_delta_log

but if I run the same job from the spark docker container, the files are created.
I've mounted the same volume on both airflow and spark containers.
This is my docker-compose file:
version: '3'

x-spark-common: &spark-common
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.spark
  volumes:
    - ./jobs:/opt/bitnami/spark/jobs
    - lakehouse:/opt/bitnami/spark/my_lakehouse
  networks:
    - ani

x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.airflow
  env_file:
    - airflow.env
  volumes:
    - ./jobs:/opt/airflow/jobs
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./spark_jar_deps:/opt/bitnami/spark/jars
    - lakehouse:/opt/bitnami/spark/my_lakehouse
  depends_on:
    - postgres
  networks:
    - ani

services:
  spark-master:
    <<: *spark-common
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"

  spark-worker-1:
    <<: *spark-common
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
  

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.0
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    networks:
      - ani

  webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - scheduler

  scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: bash -c "airflow db migrate && airflow users create --username admin --firstname abc --lastname qwe --role Admin --email abc@gmail.com --password admin@123 && airflow scheduler"

  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=pasS_123
      - MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=true
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      - ani

networks:
  ani:

volumes:
  lakehouse:
    driver: local

